# Remove a known number of documents from Mongo database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a very big database in Mongo. It has more than 69 000 documents.

I took the decision to remove the majority of them. I want to have just 10 documents, for example.

How can I randomly remove a number of documents from database inside of terminal (directly)?

I've already tried `db.col_name.remove().limit(20)` which is not working.

Comment: FWIW, 69,000 documents is nowhere near "very big".  If you're doing this because things have slowed down, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I am just testing a small application. Would it be possible? Also, I didn't find another question related to this and I think that it's good to ask.

Comment: What is random?   Do you want to keep every 10000th document or any given 10 or however many?

Comment: I want to keep only 10 documents in database after this operation. I don't want to remove them with a criteria (**not** like this: `... .remove({"age": 50})`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this directly until https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599 has been implemented.

As a workaround you can do the following. Basically, fetch a batch of _ids that you want to delete, and then do an additional `.remove()` call to actually delete them.

```
ids_to_remove = []
db.col.find({},{_id:1}).limit(100).forEach(function(doc){ids_to_remove.push(doc._id)});
db.col.remove({_id:{$in:ids_to_remove}})
```

Comment: This does what I want. Thanks!